# Magento 1.9 Include vat tax if in checkout and regisiter

Tags: magento-1.9, vat

When the customer is doing checkout and register at the same time, the VAT ID specified in the billing address its not taken in consideration. This is normal because looks like magento registers the user after the order has been completed. How can I register the user before the order is completed or calculate the final amount depending on the VAT also before the oreder takes place?

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I also spotted this today. The order is created with "not logged in" prices / vat settings, and then user is switched to correct group. Next order is correct then, but this is obviously very suboptimal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153274)